# Quotation in each string of a file

Tags: bash, scripting, quotes

Hello I am a bit lost in bash and I want to add quotes to each line so I can use them in SQL

For example input file:

```
one
two
three
```

or

```
one, two, three
```

Would be returned as:

```
'one', 'two', 'three'
```

which commands would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu-awk you can do:

```
> cat file
one, two, three
foo
bar
baz

> awk -v q="'" '{$0=q $0 q}1' RS=' *[,\n] *' file
'one'
'two'
'three'
'foo'
'bar'
'baz'
```

Comment: just tried this and I get 'one ' 
'two ' 
'three ' 'for' 'five' 'six'

Comment: it adds a space between the last character of the string and the quote in the 3 first strings

Answer (score 0):

Assuming none of the strings have single quotes or spaces in them, you can do this with a `for` loop:

```
for word in $(<infile); do echo -n "'$word', "; done | sed -e 's/, $//'
```

eg:

```
> cat infile
one
two
three

> for word in $(<infile);  do echo -n "'$word', "; done | sed -e 's/, $//'
'one', 'two', 'three'
```

Easier to read:

```
for word in $(<infile)
do
    echo -n "'$word', "
done | sed -e 's/, $//'
```

Answer (score 0):

in one-line case

```
kent$  echo "one, two, three"|awk -v q="'" '{$0=q $0 q; gsub(/, */, q", "q)}7'
'one', 'two', 'three'
```

in multilines case

```
kent$  echo "one
two
three"|awk -v q="'" -v RS="" '{$0=q $0 q;gsub(/\n/,q", "q)}7'
'one', 'two', 'three'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby -rcsv -ne '
    BEGIN {attributes = {:col_sep=>", ", :quote_char=>"'\''", :force_quotes=>true}}
    CSV.parse($_) {|row| puts CSV.generate_line(row.map {|e| e.strip}, attributes)}
' <<END
one, two, three
four
five, six
END
```

```
'one', 'two', 'three'
'four'
'five', 'six'
```